# why compiling vs2019 Simple C++ console app source requires windows sdk to compile? any workaround?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout << "hello world!\n";
    keep_open_window();
}
inline void keep_open_window() { char c=0; /*cin >> c;*/ }
```

I just don't installed WINDOWS SDK from vs2019 install option and now try to compile a simple CPP source file but it gets error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\include\yvals.h(12,10): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'crtdbg.h': No such file or directory
```

If remove all headers and just a empty main it will get below error

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
```

I searched and I found the problem is W SDK! So I wonder how could I simply compile such code without the using of SDK? ( Cause I don't think need SDK lib code for this source code, especially for a empty main with no library)

Comment: The SDK supplies all of the stuff that goes under C++ on a windows-based system. When you call `ifstream infile("myinfile");` to open a file, `ifstream ` calls down into Windows. The SDK contains the headers and other information that Visual Studio needs to do the rest of the job.

Comment: @user4581301 But What If I don't user IO and any other windows system calls? So you want to say there is no way around it but install sdk? and before I had sdk installed by default by vs2010 so no problem?

Comment: Even the set-up required to safely call an empty `main` function likely has hooks down into the OS. You need the SDK.

Comment: Back in 2010 you'd be using Visual Studio n to write code for the current version of Windows. Sometimes you'd have had to add in a different SDK to compile for, sat, Windows XP. Now-a-days things are weirder. You could be coding for Linux. A Mac. A Docker container. Crom only knows what. Since each SDK is zounds...-big (by my embedded systems coder standards at any rate) Likely Microsoft isn't forcing a download you might not need. Perhaps there is an option you missed selecting in the installation process. Been a while since I've installed Visual Studio.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks

Comment: @davisI At some level, any compiled program *must* interact with the host platform. Otherwise you could build one executable and run it everywhere, but of course that's not possible for a native app, not even an empty one that does nothing. When you target Windows, all that platform-specific "plumbing" is part of the Windows SDK, which is why you need it in order to build a working executable.

Comment: @dxiv I confused because with other version of vs and windows I didn't install any sdk ( maybe installed by vs in back ) !

Comment: @davisI The minimal SDK components were always required. Some older VC++ versions would just hide the option to *not* install it from the installer UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this fails to build is quite simple: The Windows 10 SDK contains the "Universal C Runtime" which is *required* for the Visual C/C++ Standard Library.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\<version>\ucrt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\<version>\ucrt
```

See [The Great C Runtime (CRT) Refactoring](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/the-great-c-runtime-crt-refactoring/) and [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/) from the Visual C++ Team Blog.

The implementation of the C/C++ Runtime of course *also* needs the host APIs to actually run on Windows. That's why Win32 desktop requires `kernel32.lib`.

> For Windows 10 Win32 desktop you can use `onecore.lib` instead. For UWP apps you use `WindowsApps.lib`. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-umbrella-libraries).

The Visual C++ Standard Library itself (i.e. stuff in `std` namespace) can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/STL).

Comment: shouldn't host API be on the installed windows itself? runtime! So why other programs run without sdk? ( the runtime used in compile time and built to executable file ? ) I have to read more about it and article u sent, confused.

Comment: any one could clarify this for me?

Comment: The DLLs are in Windows itself. The ``.lib`` files are only used for linking, not runtime. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/dynamic-link-library).